# Create an adaptive background image

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make text always inside the white block at any *screen resolution*?

Hence I don't want to add ant media queries for every 100px.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left-wrapper"></div>

  <div class="right-wrapper">
    <div class="conclusion-block">
      <ul class="conclusion-list content-list">
         <li>Sincerely yours,/Sincerely,</li>
         <li>Best regards,/All the best,</li>
         <li>Regards,</li>
         <li>Thank you for your consideration,</li>
         <li>Respectfully,</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
      display: flex
}

.left-wrapper {
    width: 35%;  
}

.right-wrapper {
    width: 65%;
}

.conclusion-block {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/NKTY6Du.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.conclusion-list {
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.conclusion-list li {
    font: 18px/33px Open Sans;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.18px;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

*emphasized text*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9dMP.png

*right image*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMqqw.png

Comment: I'm assuming you're hosting that image on your server and just using imgur for the question, but just in case, imgur does not allow hosting images for asset use.

Comment: I'm use it for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your background with only on image you can always try to make the text smaller/wider with vh size and change your padding with % so it can follow.

Here is an exemple:

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="right-wrapper">
   <div class="conclusion-block">
    <ul class="conclusion-list content-list">
      <li>Sincerely yours,/Sincerely,</li>
      <li>Best regards,/All the best,</li>
      <li>Regards,</li>
      <li>Thank you for your consideration,</li>
      <li>Respectfully,</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex
}

.left-wrapper {
 width: 35%;  
}
.right-wrapper {
 width: 65%;
}
.conclusion-block {
 background: url(https://i.imgur.com/NKTY6Du.png);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
ul.conclusion-list {
 padding-bottom: 75px;
 padding-top: 12%;
 padding-left: 20%;
}
.conclusion-list li {
 line-height: auto;
 font-family: Open Sans;
 font-size: 2.1vw;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: 0.18px;
 color: #333333;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

You can have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/jeymchugh/x82aqwou/

Or you can try to separate your background in different pieces so it can stay appart, this would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute units on your background image, making it the same size regardless of screen size. I just played with some numbers in my snippet below. I also disabled word wrap, so the text stays inside the image at all times.

```css
.wrapper {
      display: flex
}

.left-wrapper {
    width: 35%;  
}

.right-wrapper {
    width: 65%;
}

.conclusion-block {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/NKTY6Du.png);
    background-size: 550px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.conclusion-list {
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.conclusion-list li {
    font: 18px/33px Open Sans;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.18px;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left-wrapper"></div>

  <div class="right-wrapper">
    <div class="conclusion-block">
      <ul class="conclusion-list content-list">
         <li>Sincerely yours,/Sincerely,</li>
         <li>Best regards,/All the best,</li>
         <li>Regards,</li>
         <li>Thank you for your consideration,</li>
         <li>Respectfully,</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `transform: scale(1);`

```css
.wrapper { display: flex }

.left-wrapper { width: 35%; }

.right-wrapper { width: 65%; }

.conclusion-block { width: 550px; transform: scale(1); background: url(https://i.imgur.com/NKTY6Du.png); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; }

ul.conclusion-list { padding-bottom: 75px; padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 100px; }

.conclusion-list li { font: 18px/33px Open Sans; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 0.18px; color: #333333; margin-bottom: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left-wrapper"></div>

  <div class="right-wrapper">
    <div class="conclusion-block">
      <ul class="conclusion-list content-list">
        <li>Sincerely yours,/Sincerely,</li>
        <li>Best regards,/All the best,</li>
        <li>Regards,</li>
        <li>Thank you for your consideration,</li>
        <li>Respectfully,</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```